# IBM Mobile first 7.1 - Please suggest how load test can be performed for push notification

Tags: performance, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Can any one suggest me how load test can be performed for push notification on worklight server. Is there any tool which can be used. We expect to send approximately 10K messages every day and in future approximately 50K. As per our architecture the backend server will be making rest calls and Send Bulk Messages  [Check this documentation we following for REST API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_send_bulk_messages_post.html?lang=en)

Before we go live we want to perform a load test simulating this architecture.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform tests using standard open source tool such as JMeter by writing a script that will invoke the sendMessage requests.

Comment: Thats sounds good. But certainly I cannot have 10K devices to first subscribe push notification. Is there any way I can mock the subscription process? One way come to my mind is through database tables. Do you think entering mock data in subscription table is good way ?

Comment: That sounds feasible, yes.